Publish version catalog to mavenLocal as artifact and use on external app
I am publishing version catalog file on my project to maven local as below
build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    `version-catalog`
}

group = "com.org.myproject"
publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("version-catalog") {
        artifactId = "version-catalog"
        version = "1.0"
        artifact("../../gradle/libs.versions.toml")
    }
}

on settings.gradle.kts, I am doing as below
versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }

I am passing arifact with toml file path instead of from(components["versionCatalog"]) because using components is generating empty toml file during publishMavenLocal.
Now we I add below code to external app - settings.gradle.kts I am seeing error below
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from("com.org.myproject:version-catalog:1.0")
        }
    }
}

Error
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'incomingCatalogForLibs0'.

Could not resolve ccom.org.myproject:version-catalog:1.0.
Required by:
unspecified:unspecified:unspecified

Should I be importing published catalogs differently incase of artifact

where you able to figure out the issue? I'm facing same issue
